# Execute a String as method?

Tags: java, reflection, rmi, rpc

Is it possible to execute a String as method?

Let's say I have a server and a client. The client is send a `"sayHello()"` string.
Could the client just execute this string as method on client side, if he has a `private void sayHello()` method?

I know I could call the method by comparing the string to certain values and call functions based on this. But I'm exactly looking into something like described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection isn't very hard to code:

```
public void invokeByName(String methName) {
  try { getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methName).invoke(this); } 
  catch (RuntimeException e) { throw e; }
  catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a perfect match for [Java reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). Note however there are numerous frameworks for performing remote method invocation with Java and you're likely to be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

[Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) can do that.

Also look at [Remote Method Invocation (RMI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) which is even more specific to the stated requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A concise example:

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String methodStr = "sayHello";
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodStr).invoke(obj);
    }

    private void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("hello stackoverflow!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see `java.beans.Statement` and `java.beans.Expression`.